# Center title above table in two-column layout

Tags: html, css

How can I get my page title ("Pixel Art Maker") to be centered above the table (view [CodePen](https://codepen.io/nataliecardot/pen/MQRxJZ))? I'm not sure why it isn't already, because it (an `<h1>` element) is in the same column and no margins are applied.

[image]

I'm not sure which pieces of code are relevant, but here's the CSS code I used to create a two-column layout (along with divs in HTML):

```
.column {
  float: left;
  width: 35%;
}

.row:after {
  content: "";
  display: table;
  clear: both;
}
```

Comment: What title are you talking about? "Pixel Art Maker"? It looks centered above the grid when I look at it here

Comment: See the image I just added (does it look different than that on your browser?)

Comment: Huh. On a second look, on my browser it's actually slightly to the left, the opposite of yours lol

Comment: It's now fixed per JasonB's answer, so it should be perfectly centered (looks like it is to me).

Comment: Yeah! Looks good now (I was referring to the original one before I refreshed)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your column is 35% of the width of the screen but your pixel grid is not. If you set the width of that second column's width to `auto` the column will fit the contents and the title will be centered above the grid.

https://codepen.io/Jason_B/pen/QmMpry